# Add duration to date in google sheet formulae

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, duration

I have a duration **120:00:00.000**(120 is an hour and 00 is minute and 00 is sec) and date is **2/14/2020 13:40:00** in google sheet cells
I want to add duration and date (date + duration) using google sheet formulae

the result will be  2/19/2020 13:40:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXT(VALUE(B2)+A2; "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=TEXT(B2+A2, "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss")
```

or just:

```
=B2+A2
```

and format it internally

Comment: It's Working fine. But I have one more query. If No date and duration in B2 and A2
then no data will comes in c2. Please modify the formulae...

Comment: use: `=IF((B2<>"")*(A2<>""); TEXT(VALUE(B2)+A2; "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss"); )`

Comment: or maybe you want: `=IF((B2<>"")+(A2<>""); TEXT(VALUE(B2)+A2; "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss"); )`